# How to dynamically generate and add angular material cards with proper _ngcontent-c number?

Tags: angular

I am currently able to dynamically add angular material cards to the webpage. My problem is when I create a card it doesn't apply the class styles that I want to. I figured out that if you add _ngcontent-c(child number) in my case 18, it will give the cards the required styles. The problem is 18 is generated and will change depending on where I have the component or maybe somehow else. currently to add the card I am using code that looks like this:

```
  addFilm() {
    this.d1.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
      '<mat-card _ngcontent-c18 class="film mat-card" style="margin:2px; left:' + this.vehicleText + 'px; width:'
      + this.vehicleDuration + 'px;"></mat-card>');
  }
```

**My question is how do I either add the card so that I don't need to use nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML() or how do I add the card with inserAdjacentHTML but always get the proper _ngcontent-c?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the same using **angular renderer2**. When using angular renderer you don't have to think about _ngcontent-c angular sets them for you, when generating html.

```
const matCard = this.renderer.createElement('mat-card');

this.renderer.addClass(matCard, 'film');
this.renderer.addClass(matCard, 'mat-card');

this.renderer.setStyle(matCard, 'margin', '2px');
this.renderer.setStyle(matCard, 'left', this.vehicleText + 'px');
this.renderer.setStyle(matCard, 'width', this.vehicleDuration + 'px');

this.renderer.appendChild(this.d1.nativeElement, matCard);
```